# React Router and Firebase - show details of a specific doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I'm making a tenant recording system, using react-router v6 and FireBase v9. The home page displays cards with minimum detail and when the user clicks on the card it should take them to a more detailed page but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I have the path for the page where the document is meant to be displayed named `/doc` and a home page where the cards are under `/`.

Home page code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {useNavigate, Route, useParams, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import {db} from '../firebaseConfig';
import {collection, onSnapshot, doc} from 'firebase/firestore';

function Home() {
  const {id} = useParams();
  let nav = useNavigate();

  const toTenants=()=>{
    nav('/createTenant');

  }
  const tenantCollectionRef= collection(db, 'tenants');

  const [tenantList, setTenantList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    onSnapshot(tenantCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
     setTenantList(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
      );
      
      
    });
  }, []);

  const handleTenantClicked =  (tenant) =>{
    nav('/doc', {state:tenant});
  }
 






  return (
    <div className='Home'>
      <button className='AddTenantButton' onClick={toTenants}>Add Tenant</button>

      <div className="homePage">
        {tenantList.map((tenant)=>{
          return(
            <div className="Card" onClick={()=>{handleTenantClicked(doc.id)}}>
              <div className="CardTitle">
                <h3>{tenant.Name} {tenant.Surname}</h3>
                <h4>{tenant.Address}</h4>
                <h5>{tenant.Contact}</h5>
              </div>
            </div>

          );
        })}

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Doc code so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {collection, doc, getDoc} from 'firebase/firestore'
import {db} from '../firebaseConfig';
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


function Doc(props) {
   
  const {state} = useLocation();
  console.log(state);
 
  
   
 
   
   
   

   
  return (
    <div>
      doc
      <h1>{state.doc.Name}</h1>
      
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Doc
```

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First in `handleTenantClicked(doc.id)` you pass the id of the doc not the entire doc, you can pass the entire doc and use it like you do or you can keep passing the id and get this doc from firebase by id like this:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "tenants", props.location.state);
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
console.log(docSnap.data());
```

Comment: That appears to have worked however i am now getting this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: You can log the props and tell me what you get

Comment: problem has been fixed thanks so much for your help man

Comment: No problem :) , you can share what was the problem and how you managed to fix it!